# Hiding the automatically generated last results of an input box

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

my question is how to hide those nasty results of your last input given to an input field.
I made a picture of that and you can see how the marked result "e" hides the second input field. I dont want this to appear as I made my own livesearch and these result-set hides my live-results.

Edit for a clear question by Xenolithic:
He doesn't want text boxes to show previous things entered into it after submitted. IE: If you enter elephant and submit, if you come back to it and enter e, elephant will show up in the dropdown.

Greetings and Thx

Picture: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/fzajkh6s/Example.jpg

ANSWER:

Oh I found it out myself. 
You have to set the attribute "autocomplete" to "off" :)

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Thx and greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `autocomplete="off"` for input.

```
<input name="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is can be achieved using jquery

```
 $('input').attr('autocomplete','off');
```